Empty mounted directory in docker compose volumes
I'm trying to generate ssl certificate locally. So my project structure looks next:
projekt/
  ├── ssl_generator/
  │   ├── Dockerfile
  │   └── generate_ssl.sh
  └── docker-compose.yml

here is my docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  ssl_generator:
    build:
      context: ./ssl_generator
    volumes:
      - ./ssl:/ssl

And here is my Dockerfile inside ssl_generator
# ssl_generator/Dockerfile
FROM alpine:latest

# Install openssl
RUN apk add --no-cache openssl

# Set working directory to /ssl
WORKDIR /ssl

# Copy the SSL generation script into the container
COPY generate_ssl.sh /ssl/generate_ssl.sh

# Set proper permissions for the script
RUN chmod +x /ssl/generate_ssl.sh

# Run the script
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/ssl/generate_ssl.sh && sleep 10"]


When I run docker compose up I have this error:
/bin/sh: /ssl/generate_ssl.sh: not found

When I remove volumes from docker-compose it works, so it seems like it somehow overwrite what is going on in container. How to fix it ?

You're using a bind mount, rather than a Docker volume. When a volume is empty, it initializes with the contents defied in the image for the path it's mounted to. For a bind mount, that is not the case, whatever is on your host machine at that path will override the container's contents. If you want to initialize the directory with the contents of the container, you can launch one without the bind mount, and use docker cp to copy the files over to mount path, before starting a new container with the bind mount configured

yeah, but my goal to run docker compose up -d and get a generated certificate without any manual copying

Store your script and the data in different directories.  (Maybe put the script in /usr/local/bin.)  For something that's a one-off invocation like this, Compose may not necessarily be the right tool to manage this and a single docker run -v ... command might be better.  (There is never a reason to sleep in the container's CMD.)

Well I resolved it by using docker volume instead of bind mount, not sure if it's correct solution, but it works
